# Keys in object are getting removed when i am using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am using angular ng-repeat to add the set of input values which can be used to give the input.
how i am adding dynamically is i am taking an object and pushing into the ng-repeat variable. In the html each key in the object has a input field

javascript

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('myFirstApp', [])

.controller('MyFirstController', function ($scope) {
var flowchart=this;
  $scope.conditionslv = [];
    flowchart.field1dropdown = [{"FieldName":"","DisplayName":"select"},{"FieldName":"se","DisplayName":"se"},{"qw":"","DisplayName":"qw"}]
    flowchart.operatordropdown = [{"OperatorTypeId":'',"OperatorTypeName":"select","WFSubConditions":[]},{"OperatorTypeId":1,"OperatorTypeName":"Greater Than","WFSubConditions":[]}]
    flowchart.addconditionrow = function () {
        $scope.conditionslv.push({
            expression1: '', operatortypeid: '', expressionvalue: "", expression2value: "", comments: ""
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.conditionslv));


    }
       flowchart.cancelConditons = function () {

        flowchart.diagramshow = true;
        flowchart.conditions = false;


    }
    flowchart.saveconditions=function(){

    }



});


})();
```

html

```
            <table>
                <th>Field-1</th>

                <th>Operator</th>
                <th>Field-2</th>
                <th>Comments</th>

                <tbody>

                    <tr ng-repeat="i in conditionslv">
                      <td>{{i}}</td>

                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="i.expression1" required>
                                <option ng-repeat="item in fc.field1dropdown" value="{{item.FieldName}}">{{item.DisplayName}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="i.operatortypeid" ng-required="true" ng-options="item.OperatorTypeId as item.OperatorTypeName for item in fc.operatordropdown" ></select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="i.expressionvalue" ng-disabled="i.expression2value!=''||i.operatortypeid>5" >/<select ng-model="i.expression2value" ng-disabled="i.expressionvalue!=''||i.operatortypeid>5" required>
                                <option ng-repeat="item in fc.field1dropdown" value="{{item.FieldName}}">{{item.DisplayName}}</option>
                            </select>



                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea rows="1" cols="40" ng-model="i.comments"></textarea><span ng-click="conditionslv.splice($index,1)"
                                                                                                ng-if="conditionslv.length>1"><span class="k-icon k-font-icon k-i-x"></span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
```

most of the inputs that i am adding are the dropdowns.
the problem is if i select a dropdown value and then again selecting the select option then the key corresponding to the dropdown is getting removed from the object 
how the key is getting removed?thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may helpful..

```js
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('myFirstApp', [])

.controller('MyFirstController', function ($scope) {
var flowchart=this;
  flowchart.conditionslv = [{expression1: '', operatortypeid: '', expressionvalue: "", expression2value: "", comments: ""
        }];
    flowchart.field1dropdown = [{"FieldName":"ff","DisplayName":"select"},{"FieldName":"se","DisplayName":"se"},{"qw":"","DisplayName":"qw"}]
    flowchart.operatordropdown = [{"OperatorTypeId":'',"OperatorTypeName":"select","WFSubConditions":[]},{"OperatorTypeId":1,"OperatorTypeName":"Greater Than","WFSubConditions":[]}]
    flowchart.addconditionrow = function (valid) {
    if(valid){
        flowchart.conditionslv.push({
            expression1: '', operatortypeid: '', expressionvalue: "", expression2value: "", comments: ""
        });
      }  console.log(valid);


    }
       flowchart.cancelConditons = function () {

        flowchart.diagramshow = true;
        flowchart.conditions = false;


    }
    flowchart.saveconditions=function(){

    }

});


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myFirstApp" ng-controller="MyFirstController as ctrl">
<form name="addForm" novalidate>

<button ng-click="ctrl.addconditionrow(addForm.$valid)" ng-disabled="addForm.$invalid">Add row</button>
<table>
                <th>Field-1</th>

                <th>Operator</th>
                <th>Field-2</th>
                <th>Comments</th>

                <tbody>

                    <tr ng-repeat="i in ctrl.conditionslv">
                      <td>{{i.expression1}}{{i.operatortypeid}}{{i.expressionvalue}}{{i.expression2value}}{{i.comments}}</td>

                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="i.expression1" name="expre" required>
 <option ng-repeat="item in ctrl.field1dropdown" value="{{item.FieldName}}">{{item.DisplayName}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="i.operatortypeid" ng-required="true" ng-options="item.OperatorTypeId as item.OperatorTypeName for item in ctrl.operatordropdown" ></select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
 <input type="text" ng-model="i.expressionvalue" ng-disabled="i.expression2value!=''||i.operatortypeid>5" >/<select ng-model="i.expression2value" ng-disabled="" ng-required="i.expressionvalue!=''||i.operatortypeid>5 && i.expression2value==''">
<option ng-repeat="item in ctrl.field1dropdown" value="{{item.FieldName}}">{{item.DisplayName}}</option>
                            </select>



                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea style="width:100px" rows="1" cols="40" ng-model="i.comments" name="comment" required></textarea>
<span ng-click="ctrl.conditionslv.splice($index,1)" ng-if="ctrl.conditionslv.length>1">
<span class="k-icon k-font-icon k-i-x"></span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
            </form>
            </body>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion..if i need validations on submit then how can i validate...it jus takes like the other selected option

Comment: I was made small change.. Just check my demo

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044277/how-to-validate-inputs-dynamically-created-using-ng-repeat-ng-show-angular

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141935/angularjs-required-field-validation-in-ng-repeat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738337/how-to-use-error-required-with-ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kn1x3758/)

HTML

```
<table ng-controller="MyFirstController as fc">
  <thead>
    <th>Field-1</th>
    <th>Operator</th>
    <th>Field-2</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in conditionslv">
      <td>
        <select ng-model="i.expression1" required>
          <option ng-repeat="item in fc.field1dropdown" value="{{item.FieldName}}">{{item.DisplayName}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="i.operatortypeid" ng-required="true" ng-options="item.OperatorTypeId as item.OperatorTypeName for item in fc.operatordropdown"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="i.expressionvalue" ng-disabled="i.expression2value!=''||i.operatortypeid>5">/
        <select ng-model="i.expression2value" ng-disabled="i.expressionvalue!=''||i.operatortypeid>5" required>
          <option ng-repeat="item in fc.field1dropdown" value="{{item.FieldName}}">{{item.DisplayName}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea rows="1" cols="40" ng-model="i.comments"></textarea><span ng-click="conditionslv.splice($index,1)" ng-if="conditionslv.length>1"><span class="k-icon k-font-icon k-i-x"></span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>    
</table>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('myFirstApp', [])

.controller('MyFirstController', function($scope) {
  var flowchart = this;
  $scope.conditionslv = [];

  flowchart.field1dropdown = [{
    "FieldName": "",
    "DisplayName": "select"
  }, {
    "FieldName": "se",
    "DisplayName": "se"
  }, {
    "qw": "",
    "DisplayName": "qw"
  }];

  flowchart.operatordropdown = [{
    "OperatorTypeId": '',
    "OperatorTypeName": "select",
    "WFSubConditions": []
  }, {
    "OperatorTypeId": 1,
    "OperatorTypeName": "Greater Than",
    "WFSubConditions": []
  }];

  flowchart.addconditionrow = function() {
    $scope.conditionslv.push({
      expression1: '',
      operatortypeid: '',
      expressionvalue: "",
      expression2value: "",
      comments: ""
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.conditionslv));
  }

  flowchart.cancelConditons = function() {
    flowchart.diagramshow = true;
    flowchart.conditions = false;
  }

  flowchart.saveconditions = function() {

  } 
  flowchart.addconditionrow();
});
```

Comment: gaurav please check the above fiddle i jus added the object..you can clearly see the variable getting deleted from the object.

Comment: Which variable from which object?

Comment: can you please check the fiddle change the first dropdown to option and then to select.you can see the object in the first row..you can observe the values removing

Comment: U need to define `FieldName` property for all object in `field1dropdown` Array, blank string as a value will remove key from object. check working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kn1x3758/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**Need some clarifications :**

- From where this `flowchart.addconditionrow()` is executing ?
- As you are pushing the single object into `$scope.conditionslv` array then why are you using `ng-repeat` ?. you can directly assign object property into the `ng-model`.

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  var flowchart = this;
  $scope.conditionslv = [];
  flowchart.field1dropdown = [{
    "FieldName": "",
    "DisplayName": "select"
  }, {
    "FieldName": "se",
    "DisplayName": "se"
  }, {
    "qw": "",
    "DisplayName": "qw"
  }]
  flowchart.operatordropdown = [{
    "OperatorTypeId": '',
    "OperatorTypeName": "select",
    "WFSubConditions": []
  }, {
    "OperatorTypeId": 1,
    "OperatorTypeName": "Greater Than",
    "WFSubConditions": []
  }]
  flowchart.addconditionrow = function() {
    $scope.conditionslv.push({
      expression1: '',
      operatortypeid: '',
      expressionvalue: "",
      expression2value: "",
      comments: ""
    });
  }
  flowchart.addconditionrow();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController as fc">
   <table>
                <th>Field-1</th>

                <th>Operator</th>
                <th>Field-2</th>
                <th>Comments</th>

                <tbody>

                    <tr ng-repeat="i in conditionslv">
                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="i.expression1" required>
                                <option ng-repeat="item in fc.field1dropdown" value="{{item.FieldName}}">{{item.DisplayName}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="i.operatortypeid" ng-required="true" ng-options="item.OperatorTypeId as item.OperatorTypeName for item in fc.operatordropdown" ></select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="i.expressionvalue" ng-disabled="i.expression2value!=''||i.operatortypeid>5" >/<select ng-model="i.expression2value" ng-disabled="i.expressionvalue!=''||i.operatortypeid>5" required>
                                <option ng-repeat="item in fc.field1dropdown" value="{{item.FieldName}}">{{item.DisplayName}}</option>
                            </select>



                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea rows="1" cols="40" ng-model="i.comments"></textarea><span ng-click="conditionslv.splice($index,1)"
                                                                                                ng-if="conditionslv.length>1"><span class="k-icon k-font-icon k-i-x"></span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
            <div>
```

Comment: hi rohit there is button in the ui that can be used to call the method.....